# Invertible matrices over noncommutative rings

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, noncommutative-rings

Let $A\in M_m(R)$ be an invertible square matrix over a **noncommutative** ring $R$. Is the transpose matrix $A^t$ also invertible? If it isn't, are there any easy counterexamples?

The question popped up while working on a paper. We need to impose that the *transpose* of certain matrix of endomorphisms is invertible, and we wondered if that was the same as asking if the matrix is invertible.

Comment: +1 as the question is more subtle than it seems...

Comment: It is a classical observation due to Nathan Jacobson that a division ring such the set of invertible matrices is closed under transposition has to be a field, i.e. commutative. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47369/example-for-column-rank-neq-row-rank

Comment: I cannot / could not believe that this is not true in general.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See: R.N. Gupta, Anjana Khurana, Dinesh Khurana, and T.Y. Lam, 
[Rings over which the transpose of every invertible matrix is invertible](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869309003482); J. Algebra 322 (2009), no. 5, 1627–1636 ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2543626)).

Abstract:  We prove that the transpose of every invertible square matrix over a ring $R$ is invertible if and only if $R/\text{rad}(R)$ is commutative.  …

Comment: Note that the $\Longleftarrow$ direction is trivial (once you know that the Jacobson radical of a matrix ring is the ideal of all matrices which have all of their entries lying in the Jacobson radical of the ring itself).

Comment: This completely address my question. Thank you very much, Alireza!